# How to get Automatic Serial number column in the HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I need to get serial number automatically in one of my column in the table.

Here is my sample code:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pages/common/taglibs.jspf"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/styles/tablesort.css'/>" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery.tablesort.js'/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
table tr td{
text-align:center;
}
</style>


<body>
<div id="tabs" style="width: 880px;">
  <c:if test="${ model != null}">

                <table id="commentsTable" class="tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>S.NO<th/>
                        <th><spring:message code="title" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="CommentsValue" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="By" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="date" /></th> 
                        <th><spring:message code="comments" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="By" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="LateUser" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="LateTimestamp" /></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="row" items="${model}">
                        <tr>
                        <td>Need to get automatic serial numbers value here<td>
                        <td>HTML</td>
                        <td style="word-break:break-all;">Mount</td>
                        <td>1234</td>
                        <td>2345</td>
                        <td style="word-break:break-all;">2345</td>
                        <td>token</td>
                        <td>right</td>
                        <td>10982</td>
                        </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </c:if>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What did you try to do this? Where excactly is your problem/ error?

Comment: need to get serial number column automatically in my html table

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Pure CSS Solution

see that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/AGYnt/)

**HTML:** (a simple table with a blank `td` that will hold the counter)

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Automatic Serial number</th>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--leave it blank-->
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--leave it blank-->
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--leave it blank-->
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--leave it blank-->
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--leave it blank-->
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--leave it blank-->
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--leave it blank-->
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--leave it blank-->
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
body
{
    counter-reset: Serial;           /* Set the Serial counter to 0 */
}

table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
}

tr td:first-child:before
{
  counter-increment: Serial;      /* Increment the Serial counter */
  content: "Serial is: " counter(Serial); /* Display the counter */
}
```

if you want to target specific table, just give it a class, and target those `tr`s specifically.

html

```
<table class="auto-index">
.
.
.
```

css

```
.auto-index td:first-child:before
{
  counter-increment: Serial;      /* Increment the Serial counter */
  content: "Serial is: " counter(Serial); /* Display the counter */
}
```

Comment: @avrahamcool ... How to reset the counter for each table if the webpage have more than one row. That is the counter countinue from serial no of last row of the previous table to the 1st row of the next table .

That is if table 1 ends with serial no 10 , then table 2 starts from 11. But I want the table 2 to start from 1.

Comment: @RageshDAntony reset the counter for each first row. like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AGYnt/28/)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was wondering what if I'd like to apply this Serial index only for one of my tables, what shall I say in my <tr > tag? i.e. how to translate the css statement "tr td:first-child:before" into the style statement in <tr> tag?

Answer (score 8):

Leave the first column as blank and call a javascript method to add serial numbers. An example is shown below

```
var addSerialNumber = function () {
    $('table tr').each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').html(index+1);
    });
};

addSerialNumber();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/DgUG2/

Comment: can you please say how to call the function inside my javascript template.it is not working after pasting your code in my javascript template

Comment: In your code, add the javascript from that jsfiddle and copy in your file after $("#tabs").tabs();

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  
  var addSerialNumber = function () {
      var i = 1
      $('table tr').each(function(index) {
          $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').html(index+1);
      });
  };
  addSerialNumber();
 }); 
</script>

Answer (score 3):

```
    <%! int i = 1; %> 
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="row" items="${model}">
                        <tr>
                        <td><%= i; %> <%! i++; %> <td>
                        <td>HTML</td>
                        <td style="word-break:break-all;">Mount</td>
                        <td>1234</td>
                        <td>2345</td>
                        <td style="word-break:break-all;">2345</td>
                        <td>token</td>
                        <td>right</td>
                        <td>10982</td>
                        </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
```

try this jsp code.

in Sql Try this

```
SELECT  @a:=@a+1 serial_number,marks,(need fields in you db) FROM
student_marks(your db name),(SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have a header in your htmp page.... use the following code

```
var addSerialNumber = function () {
    var i = 0
    $('table tr').each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').html(index-1+1);
    });
};

addSerialNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :- Read the comments for better understanding

```
<% int i = 1; %>   //  --> It will declare value of i as 1
    <c:forEach>
    <tr>
            <td><%= i %> <% i++; %></td>  // --> It will display and increment the value
            <td>${product.productDescription}</td>
            <td>${products.warehouseQuantity}</td>
             <td>${product.productPrice }</td>
            <td>Rs ${product.productDiscount }</td>
            <td>Rs ${product.productPricePerQuantity }</td>
    </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the correct answer has already been given, but I had same question but my table rows will be appended dynamically so, the answer wasn't helpful to me.

Incase anyone ever run into my type of problem where you need to update table and need index, like add-to-cart in e-commerce sites then we can use this.
I used the DOM property called **childElementCount** on the table which returns the number of child elements of an element.

```js
function func(){
let index = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].childElementCount
  $('table').append(`
    <tr class="items--row">
        <td class="ind">${index}</td>
        <td>Chocolate</td>
        <td>$23</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$230</td>
    </tr>
    `);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
                <tr class="head--row">
                    <th>S.no</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                </tr>
                
</table>
<button onclick="func()">Sample</button>
```